# Why will this code not work in my production environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code below works perfectly in Dev and Stage environment but not Production.  Stage and Prod are both on IIS7.  I've confirmed that litTest is being set and shows on the page but the class never appears on the html control in prod.  Im baffled!

```
 protected void lvQuestionList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {            

        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        TT.BusinessLogic.stQuestion question = (TT.BusinessLogic.stQuestion)dataItem.DataItem;

        HtmlControl tr = (HtmlControl)dataItem.FindControl("trRow");
        if (tr != null && question.stStatus.Status == "New")
            tr.Attributes.Add("class", "direct-row");

        if (SortedAnimation != null && question.QuestionId == new Guid(SortedAnimation))
        {

            if (tr != null && question.stStatus.Status == "New")

                tr.Attributes["class"] = "sortanim direct-row";
            else
            {

                tr.Attributes["class"] = "sortanim";
                litTest.Text = SortedAnimation + "test";
            }

            SortedAnimation = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Should also mention this listview is in an UpdatePanel.

Comment: how does it not work? could you elaborate?

Comment: What "class" doesn't display? I see you are setting classes in two spots "sortanim" and "direct-row"

Comment: These lines get hit but the class is never actually add in the html  tr.Attributes["class"] = "sortanim";
litTest.Text = SortedAnimation + "test";
Im starting to wonder if the listview is getting bound twice and the second bind is wiping out the class.  investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Pulled data from Prod a was able to recreate.  It was double binding and the second bind was wiping out the class.  I forgot that this was firing automatically and i didn't need to explicitly bind after a sort.

```
protected void dpListView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bindFilteredQuestions();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget you can mark your own answer as the solution!